# Delete all rows before the first appearance of a condition in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Person":[1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                   "Bank":["B1","B2","B9","B2","B6","B1","B1","B5",]})

   Person Bank
0       1   B1
1       1   B2
2       2   B9
3       2   B2
4       3   B6
5       3   B1
6       3   B1
7       3   B5
```

I want to drop all the rows of each person that go before the first time `B1` appears. That is, I want to keep the rows where `Bank == B1` and the following ones.

This is what I want to get:

```py
   Person Bank
0       1   B1
1       1   B2
5       3   B1
6       3   B1
7       3   B5
```

If `B1` never happens, then clear all the rows that belong to that person. If there's rows before the first appearance of `B1`, I want to drop them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `mask` + `ffill`

```
m = df['Bank'].where(df['Bank'] == 'B1').groupby(df['Person']).ffill()

df[m.notnull()]
```

```
   Person Bank
0       1   B1
1       1   B2
5       3   B1
6       3   B1
7       3   B5
```

---

This works by making everything after the first occurrence in a group a non-null value.  This is done in two steps:

1) Mask everything that *isn't* valid.

```
df['Bank'].where(df['Bank'] == 'B1')
```

```
0     B1
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5     B1
6     B1
7    NaN
Name: Bank, dtype: object
```

2) Fill forward per group.  This is the real key to the answer.  This means that all values after the first occurrence in `B1` will be filled with valid strings (***per group***), so they won't be removed by `notnull`

```
>>> m
0     B1
1     B1
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5     B1
6     B1
7     B1
Name: Bank, dtype: object
```

Once we have the valid mask, it's trivial to filter the DataFrame where the mask is not null.

Comment: Can you explain why this works? I can see that `df.Bank.where(df.bank == "B1")` returns the people IDs in the rows that match the condition. What does grouping by person and `ffill()` do?

Comment: @ArturoSbr I updated my answer showing the intermediate results

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! Does `ffill()` stand for "forward fill"?

Comment: Yes, it does.  [Other types can be found here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna)

Answer (score 2):

Using `cumsum` and their bool correspondents (`astype(bool)`)

```
df[df.groupby('Person').Bank.transform(lambda s: s.eq('B1').cumsum().astype(bool))]
```

---

```
   Person Bank
0       1   B1
1       1   B2
5       3   B1
6       3   B1
7       3   B5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check with `transform`

```
s=(df['Bank']=='B1').groupby(df['Person'])

df[(df.index>=(s.transform('idxmax')))&s.transform('any')]
Out[305]: 
   Person Bank
0       1   B1
1       1   B2
5       3   B1
6       3   B1
7       3   B5
```

Comment: I want to exclude `B6` and keep `B5` from `Person 3`.

Comment: @ArturoSbr in your question, your printed DataFrame and code DataFrame don't match.  The latter is missing a row