# Delete all rows after the first appearance of a condition in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Working with the following example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Person":[1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3], "Bank":["OPEN","OPEN","OPEN","OPEN","CLOSED","OPEN","OPEN","CLOSED","CLOSED"]})

   Person   Bank
0       1   OPEN
1       1   OPEN
2       2   OPEN
3       2   OPEN
4       2   CLOSED
5       2   OPEN
6       3   OPEN
7       3   CLOSED
8       3   CLOSED
```

I'd like to produce an output that keeps all rows up to and including the first occurrence of `CLOSED` with each `Person` group. So it should look like:

```
   Person   Bank
0       1   OPEN
1       1   OPEN
2       2   OPEN
3       2   OPEN
4       2   CLOSED
6       3   OPEN
7       3   CLOSED
```

I was able to use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57530661/delete-all-rows-before-the-first-appearance-of-a-condition-in-a-pandas-data-fram) to build an output that's close:

```
mask = (df['Bank']
    .where(df['Bank'] == 'OPEN')
    .groupby(df['Person'])
    .ffill(limit=1)
)
df[mask.notnull()]

# The above produces this
   Person   Bank
0       1   OPEN
1       1   OPEN
2       2   OPEN
3       2   OPEN
4       2   CLOSED
5       2   OPEN
6       3   OPEN
7       3   CLOSED
```

So my current code doesn't handle the case of something moving from `CLOSED` back to `OPEN`. Is there a good way to do this that isn't extremely slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the mask with a `groupby`. It requires 2 operations `cummax` + `shift` so the straight forward method is to use a slower apply, but for many groups you'll see better performance from 2 separate `groupby` calls using the built-in operations

```
m = (df['Bank'].eq('CLOSED')
       .groupby(df['Person'])
       .apply(lambda x: ~x.cummax().shift().fillna(False)))

# or
m = ~(df['Bank'].eq('CLOSED')
        .groupby(df['Person']).cummax()
        .groupby(df['Person']).shift()
        .fillna(False))

df[m]
   Person    Bank
0       1    OPEN
1       1    OPEN
2       2    OPEN
3       2    OPEN
4       2  CLOSED
6       3    OPEN
7       3  CLOSED
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Person":[1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3], "Bank":["OPEN","OPEN","OPEN","OPEN","CLOSED","OPEN","OPEN","CLOSED","CLOSED"]})
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    try:
        if df.iloc[i,:]["Bank"] == "CLOSED" and df.iloc[i+1,:]["Person"] == df.iloc[i,:]["Person"]:
            df.drop(df.index[i+1], axis=0, inplace=True).reset_index(True)
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most elegant solution but seems to work for my test scenarios:

**Code:**

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Person":[1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3], "Bank":["OPEN","OPEN","OPEN","OPEN","CLOSED","OPEN","CLOSED","OPEN","CLOSED","CLOSED"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Person":[1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3], "Bank":["CLOSED","OPEN","OPEN","OPEN","CLOSED","OPEN","CLOSED","OPEN","CLOSED","CLOSED"]})


def process_data(df):
    persons = df['Person'].unique()
    idx_arr = []
    for p in persons:
        mask1 = df['Person'] == p
        mask2 = (df['Bank'] == "CLOSED") & mask1
        idx_arr += range(list(mask1).index(True), 1+list(mask1&mask2).index(True) if any(mask2) else
        len(mask1) - 1 - list(mask1)[::-1].index(True)+1)

    return df.iloc[idx_arr]

print(process_data(df1))
print(process_data(df2))
```

**Input 1:**

```
   Person    Bank
0       1    OPEN
1       1    OPEN
2       2    OPEN
3       2    OPEN
4       2  CLOSED
5       2    OPEN
6       2  CLOSED
7       3    OPEN
8       3  CLOSED
9       3  CLOSED
```

**Output 1:**

```
   Person    Bank
0       1    OPEN
1       1    OPEN
2       2    OPEN
3       2    OPEN
4       2  CLOSED
7       3    OPEN
8       3  CLOSED
```

**Input 2:**

```
   Person    Bank
0       1  CLOSED
1       1    OPEN
2       2    OPEN
3       2    OPEN
4       2  CLOSED
5       2    OPEN
6       2  CLOSED
7       3    OPEN
8       3  CLOSED
9       3  CLOSED
```

**Output 2:**

```
   Person    Bank
0       1  CLOSED
2       2    OPEN
3       2    OPEN
4       2  CLOSED
7       3    OPEN
8       3  CLOSED
```